# Files uploaded using Apache Common Net FTPClient.storeFileStream are corrupted

Tags: java, ftp, upload, apache-commons-net

I wrote a code for compressing database file (.zip) and uploading to an FTP server. When I download that from server, files are corrupted. What can be the reason for that?

Code:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();      

ftpClient.connect(server, port);
ftpClient.login(user, pass);
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);                 
  
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd");  
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(); 
String currentDate = dtf.format(now);
         
String srcFilename = file;

String remoteFile = "STORE_" + currentDate + ".zip";
       
try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    OutputStream fos = ftpClient.storeFileStream(remoteFile);
    try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {
        File srcFile = new File(srcFilename);
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcFile)) {
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(srcFile.getName()));
            int length;
            while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();
        }
    }
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Error creating zip file" + ioe);
}

if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file upload initiated by [`FTPClient.storeFileStream` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFileStream(java.lang.String)) has to be finished by closing the stream and calling [`FTPClient.completePendingCommand`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#completePendingCommand()):

> You must close the OutputStream when you finish writing to it. The OutputStream itself will take care of closing the parent data connection socket upon being closed.
>
> **To finalize the file transfer you must call [`completePendingCommand`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#completePendingCommand()) and check its return value to verify success.** If this is not done, subsequent commands may behave unexpectedly.